# Filling only parts of a ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, filling

I have a set of {x,y} data that shows a measurement value over time on the x axis. I'd like to highlight several chunks of time on my ListLinePlot by filling the plot to the axis for only certain x-ranges (say, 10-20 and 55-96).

I've tried the methods outlined here: [ListLinePlot partial filling](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87451/listlineplot-partial-filling)

```
data1 = movavgjoined; data1[[;; 9]] = Null; data1[[21 ;;]] = Null;
ListLinePlot[{movavgjoined, data1}, Filling -> {2 -> Axis}]
```

But the output is just the original graph.

Edit: here's some sample data

```
movavgjoined = {{0.00416667,5.50648},{0.00833333,5.51119},{0.0125,5.51531}, 
 {0.0166667,5.51983},{0.0208333,5.52381},{0.025,5.52728},{0.0291667,5.53126}, 
 {0.0333333,5.53551},{0.0375,5.53966},{0.0416667,5.54449},{0.0458333,5.54942}, 
 {0.05,5.55455},{0.0541667,5.55929},{0.0583333,5.56368},{0.0625,5.56793}, 
 {0.0666667,5.57214},{0.0708333,5.57568},{0.075,5.57774},{0.0791667,5.57921}, 
 {0.0833333,5.58106},{0.0875,5.58391},{0.0916667,5.5875},{0.0958333,5.59185}, 
 {0.1,5.59556},{0.104167,5.59932},{0.108333,5.60445},{0.1125,5.61067}, 
 {0.116667,5.61925},{0.120833,5.62737},{0.125,5.63508},{0.129167,5.64551}, 
 {0.133333,5.65654},{0.1375,5.665},{0.141667,5.67078},{0.145833,5.67456}, 
 {0.15,5.67668},{0.154167,5.67757},{0.158333,5.67719},{0.1625,5.67757}, 
 {0.166667,5.68031}};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
yintervals = {{5.55, 5.58}, {5.61, 5.66}};
data2 = If[IntervalMemberQ[IntervalUnion @@ (Interval /@ yintervals), #[[2]]], 
 #, {#[[1]], Null}] & /@ movavgjoined;

ListLinePlot[{movavgjoined, data2}, Filling -> {2 -> Axis}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][1]]
```

[image]

```
xintervals = {{.05, .08}, {.11, .13}};
data3 = If[IntervalMemberQ[IntervalUnion @@ (Interval /@ xintervals), #[[1]]], 
    #, {#[[1]], Null}] & /@ movavgjoined;

ListLinePlot[{movavgjoined, data3}, Filling -> {2 -> Axis}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Okay so this is working but it's filling the wrong part of my plot. I think this is because these functions call the nth list element rather than as a range of y values. My y values are time values in minutes/fractions of minutes and are irregularly spaced. So the 10th-20th time point is being filled as opposed to 10 minutes-20 minutes.

Comment: @user63997, it would be easier to suggest a solution if you can post  your `movavgjoined`.

Comment: True! I edited the original post with some sample data. It's a big list, so I just included the first few points so you get the idea.

Comment: Shoot, I see now that I made a mistake in my original post. The X axis is the time points, not the Y. So the above code uses a y-range which you've defined. The graph is exactly what I'm wanting, though. So say here instead of defining the y values, the time ranges on the x axis that I'd like to fill are {0.5, 0.8} and {0.11,0.13}. Would the code be the same?

Comment: @user63997, updated with the version that uses intervals of x-coordinates.

Comment: Thanks so much! Works perfectly.

Comment: @user63997, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.